# "Cripple" vs "Break"

Tags: word-difference, word-in-context

When speaking about bones and body parts what is the difference between a **crippled body part/bone** and a **broken body part/bone**?

- A crippled leg
- A broken arm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *crippled* limb means the person is not able to fully use the limb for some reason (perhaps due to an injury, illness, or birth defect). Words are flexible so this may not always hold true, but, generally speaking, *injured* may imply a full recovery is expected, while *crippled* may imply a more permanent disability.

A *broken* limb simply means the bone has been fractured (either a crack or a full break):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Crippling implies *permanent* disability, and is not related to a specific type of injury.  For example you can have *crippling* nerve damage, or *crippling* joint pain, or even *crippling* headaches (if they occur so often that you can't function normally).

So "a crippled leg" is one that is permanently injured, or at least one that's not likely to heal.  A "broken arm" means the bone has been fractured, but is expected to heal.

Comment: So cripple doesn't necessarily imply physical damage?

Comment: Well, *all* damage is physical in some way, but I get what you are asking.  It depends on the context.  A "crippled leg" is assumed to be due to injury, so if it isn't (and the information is important) you should explain how it got that way.

Comment: @Andrew - Diseases such as smallpox can cripple a leg.

Comment: @J.R.  I think you mean *polio* not smallpox but, yes I agree you can be crippled by disease, and also congenital deformity, age-related deterioration, psychological trauma, and other factors.

Comment: @SovereignSun "Crippling" can be applied to anything which normally does something but cannot for some reason (such as being damaged).  One can "cripple" a contract by writing the wording in a way that cannot be enforced.

Comment: @CortAmmon - Excellent point! Interestingly enough, the word _broken_ can be used in similar (and one might say figurative) ways. The phrases _broken promises, broken hearts,_ and _broken treaties_ come to mind.